# Repair bad Ogg Vorbis export from Audacity?

Tags: audacity

I have a voice recording that I made in Audacity and then exported as Ogg Vorbis format. I just listened to it for the first time, and it contains what I can only describe as *skips* — a word or two just missing, here and there.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone have a suggestion of alternative OGG decoders that might restore the complete audio signal? I have tried reading back the file with Audacity and `sox`, but the results are identical.

The situation is somewhat dire, as the audio recording contains the testimonial of a woman who died shortly after the recording was made. Thanks for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Your situation is dire. There is no way to recover the audio. Audacity is not a program you should use for anything mission critical. Ogg Vorbis is not a format that you should be using for mastering mission critical audio. There are no "alternative" ogg decoders. All OGG decoders will be using the same OGG and VORBIS libraries that everyone else uses. It's quite likely that the setup of audacity was incorrect initially and you were basically dropping audio buffers on record. Unfortunately I don't see any way around this if your master is missing packets.